# Passing Data between two usercontrols in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have a UC_Categories.ascx  **( UC_1 )** which constraints categoryname . UC_Products.ascx **( UC_2 )** will show products by categoryname. Both of them are in a **Page** called BookShop.aspx ( Page )

In the Page, when user click a **UC_1** (step 1 ) , it will render a **UC_2** by categoryname (step2 ). I process step 1 by sending a request with param that is categoryname to **Page**. Step2  create a new **UC_2** ,set Properties value that is categoryname , and execute FillProductByCategoryName method. then add **UC_2** to a PlaceHolder in the Page. but i don't show **UC_2** .

I need a help or suggest from everyone.

Thank you for reading my question!
ps : my english isn't very well.

in the codebehind of the UC2 :

```
public void FillProduct()
    {

        ProductsMN productsMN = new ProductsMN();
        if (dlBook == null)
        {
            dlBook = new DataList();
            dlBook.DataSource = productsMN.GetByCategoryName(CategoryName);
            dlBook.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            dlBook.DataSource = productsMN.GetByCategoryName(CategoryName);
            dlBook.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
```

in the codebehind of the page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        }
        string categoryName = Request.QueryString["categoryName"] as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(categoryName))
        {
            BookContent.Controls.Clear(); // BookContent : Placeholder
            Control c = Page.LoadControl("~/UC/UC_Books.ascx") as UC.UC_Books;
            UC.UC_Books ucBook = new UC.UC_Books();
            ucBook.CategoryName = categoryName;
            ucBook.FillProduct(); //line 10
            BookContent.Controls.Add(ucBook); //line 11
        }

    }
```

at the PageLoad of the Page, useBook contains data. but in the Page (view ), i don't see data. i think //line11 isn't execute or not true .

Comment: Have you tried public property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose public properties and a constructor of the UserControl's Controls to the parent page.

Say your Usercontrol has got a label:

```
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server" visible="true"/>
```

In the codebehind of the UserControl add this.

```
    //Constructor
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        Category = new Label();
    }
    //Exposing the Label
    public Label Category
    {
        get { return this.MyLabel; }
        set { this.MyLabel = value; }
    }
```

Assume you have added the UserControl to the parent page and its ID is "MyUserControl".

To set the label value of the UserControl to something use this:

```
MyUserControl.Category.Text=Response.QueryString["categoryname"];//Obviously you would want to encode it first.
```

If you need to call functions of the parent page in the UserControl's codebehind, you will have to use delegates. I would not recommend this method though.