# How to change an item visibility in sitecore from different ascx.cs

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sublayout

I am using the code

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.RendererField Thecontent = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.RendererField)Sitecore.
            Context.Database.GetItem("my item path").Fields["Text"];
        if (Thecontent != null)
        {
            Thecontent. .. ????????
        }
```

I want to hide it. This field is in another ascx and I want to access it from another sublayout.

Comment: The rule to hide the renderer needs to be in the other ascx? I mean, is it possible to you to evaluate this rule in somewhere else (.cs)?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  The question doesn't give much clue.

Answer (score 1):

The context item should be available from all of the sublayouts.

However if you want to communicate between different user controls, then this question is not a specific to Sitecore, and has been addressed here:

- [Passing Data between two usercontrols in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589232/passing-data-between-two-usercontrols-in-asp-net)
- http://spreadingmyideas.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/communication-between-web-user-controls.html
- http://blog.weareon.net/how-to-communicate-between-two-user-controls-using-event-aggregator/

and plenty more if you check Google:

https://www.google.com/?q=communication+between+user+controls